# how to keep app running when library is crashed?

Tags: android

I wrote a common library for other apps. In order to improve the user experience, I would like to keep apps running as if the library is not added when the library has some exceptions.
Is it possible to do so?

Comment: you can use try catch block for any exception and handle it your way ...
but you cannot totally stop an exception

Comment: There's nothing special about a library - in fact at runtime there is no such distinction, just a bunch of code in whatever namespace(s) it was written in.

Answer (score 1):

try-catch it's the simplest thing you can do!!

This is my edit:

sorry bro ..It was a short answer...

You can handle your exception generally by try-catch.. And you can implement that try-catch whether inside your library classes or inside your app code (But it's better inside your library).. For example the audio inside the android it's not important enough to close our app if it failed, so we always handle the exceptions that may occur when we deal with audio because it's not an important part of the app (it's important for video and audio apps)...

And here is an important note: don't handle the exception with catch(exception e) then your program doesn't handle every possible exception correctly and perfectly.. So handle every single exception alone!!!

But i was wondering... Why your library may be crushed when working with?? why you don't try to solve all the exceptions that may occur and make your program safe and more flexible?? :)

I hope it was helpful :)

Comment: Hiya, this may well solve the problem... but it'd be good if you could edit your answer and provide a little more explanation about how and why it works :) Don't forget - there are heaps of newbies on Stack overflow, and they could learn a thing or two from your expertise - what's obvious to you might not be so to them.

Comment: This is very much an answer - simple, practical, and to the point.

Comment: Hi Mohammad, thanks for your answer. I have this requirement is because that none of us can guarantee there will never be any crush in his/her program. And I don't wanna any potential crush affect other apps.

Answer (score 0):

A typical approach in servers is for a "core" part to catch all exceptions in a "request processing" part it invoked and send them to log and/or user. This way, no errors in request processing can bring down the server as a whole.